# Jquery.switchclass is not loading properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

2 part question.

1. So I want to be able to click the square at the middle which should slide the top left box to the right horizontally, and the top right box will slide to the bottom vertically, etc.

Duration being 2 seconds for the slide.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#container").click(function(){
        $("#box1, #box3").switchClass("horizontal", "newVertical", 1000);
        $("#box2, #box4").switchClass("vertical", "newHorizontal", 1000);

    });
});
```

1. in Fiddle animation is running. Does NOT run in chrome or firefox. Am I using the correct cdn?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Cie Studios | Solution</title>
<!--Stylesheet-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ciestyle.css">




</head>

<body>
<section id="main">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="horizontal" id="box1">1</div>
        <div class="vertical" id="box2">2</div>
        <div class="vertical" id="box3">3</div>
        <div class="horizontal" id="box4">4</div>
    </div>
        <label>Fig 1.2</label>
</section>
<!--Google JQuery Lib -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!--Javascript -->
<script src="ciescript.js"></script>
</body>
</html
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin:0px auto;
}

#main {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:20%;
    text-align:center;
}

#container {
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:#333333;
    height:151px;
    width:151px;
}

.horizontal {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
}

.vertical {
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
}

.newHorizontal {
    width:100px!important;
    height:50px!important;
    float:left!important;
    border:0px!important;
}

.newVertical {
    width:50px!important;
    height:100px!important;
    float:right!important;
    border:0px!important;
}

#box1, #box3 {
    float:left;
}

#box2, #box4 {
    float:right;
}

#box1 {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}

#box2 {
    background-color:#cccccc;
    border-left:1px solid #000000;
}

#box3 {
    background-color:#999999;
    border-right:1px solid #000000;
}

#box4 {
    background-color:#666666;
    border-top:1px solid #000000;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#container").click(function(){
        $("#box1, #box3").switchClass("horizontal", "newVertical", 1000);
        $("#box2, #box4").switchClass("vertical", "newHorizontal", 1000);

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pcdqz/1/

Comment: Add ` <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` before jquery ui link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JqueryUI has a dependency on Jquery.

Add `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>` or a similar cdn link prior to loading JqueryUI.